# Need to change every element in array but just the index is being changed java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a program and I am trying to reduce the cost of the books by 40%. Now my issue is that I am able to reduce any book in the array that I specifiy but not every book in the array. I'm unsure of how to get the method to go every element in the array. I know that it is changing the index because I have 0 in [0] for example. My question is what do I do so it sorts through the whole array and not just the one index. This is happening in the reduceBook method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Book[] bookArray = new Book[6];

    bookArray[0] = new Book("Java Proramming", "Liang", 1320, 145.00); 
    bookArray[1] = new Book("Horton Hears a Who", "Dr. Seuss", 72, 19.99);
    bookArray[2] = new Book("The Hobbit", "Tolkien", 320, 9.25);
    bookArray[3] = new Book("Born a Crime", "Noah", 304, 17.33);
    bookArray[4] = new Book();
    bookArray[5] = new Book();

    for(Book b : bookArray)
        System.out.println(b);
    finishArray(bookArray);
    System.out.println("\nThis is a space between the old array and the new finished one ");
    for(Book b : bookArray)
        System.out.println(b);

    System.out.println("\nThis should print out the discounted books ");
    reduceBooks(bookArray);
    for(Book b : bookArray)
        System.out.println(b);
}

// public void finishArray(String[] Book) {
public static void finishArray(Book[] bookara) {
    bookara[4].setTitle("The Town");
    bookara[4].setAuthor("Chuck Hogan");
    bookara[4].setPages(477);
    bookara[4].setPrice(14.99);
    bookara[5].setTitle("Cat and Mouse");
    bookara[5].setAuthor("James Patterson");
    bookara[5].setPages(358);
    bookara[5].setPrice(9.99);
}
public static Book reduceBooks(Book[] reduceAra) {//This is the trouble area
    Book bookReduce = reduceAra[0]; //So here if I change the index 
 //it will reduce the book in it by 40% but I need to reduce all the books in the array.
    double price = bookReduce.getPrice();
    for (int i = 0; i < reduceAra.length; i++) {

        double reducedPrice = price * .60;
        bookReduce.setPrice(reducedPrice);
    }

    return bookReduce;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the book array like you did to print, but instead lower the cost

```
for(Book b : bookArray) {
    b.setPrice(b.getPrice() * 0.6)
}
```

Comment: The problem is in the return value. It will always return [0]. OP needs to return the array or pass the index he cares about. The for loop is useless

Comment: This solves it very easily. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: @Boomboxcity Look at the code your for loop is useless. You are hardcoding [0] iterating over the array with no purpose. You need to pass the index or return the array

Answer (score 0):

You can code the method reduceBook this way:

```
public static void reduceBooks(Book[] reduceAra) {      
     for (int i = 0; i < reduceAra.length; i++) {       
            Book bookReduce = reduceAra[i];
            double price = bookReduce.getPrice();
            double reducedPrice = price * .60;
            bookReduce.setPrice(reducedPrice);
     }
 }
```

or even in a more compact style:

```
public static void reduceBooks(Book[] reduceAra) {
    for (int i = 0; i < reduceAra.length; i++) {
        Book bookReduce = reduceAra[i];
        bookReduce.setPrice(bookReduce.getPrice() * 0.60);
    }
}
```

Dominique Ubersfeld

Answer (score 0):

just loop the reduceBooks method

```
public static Book reduceBooks(Book[] reduceAra) {

        for(Book b : reduceAra){
            double price = b.getPrice();
        price = price * .60;
        b.setPrice(price);
    }
        return bookReduce;

    }
```